# winAPI GetAdaptersAddresses unprintable friendly name

Tags: winapi

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses)
Why are some of the user friendly names in PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES unprintable? (aswell as a few other attributes such as dns suffix)

By unprintable, I mean containing non-printable characters. for exmaple, the first character in one of the friendly names I tested had a unicode value fo 8207 (decimal)

[image]

A minimal complete viable example

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES adapterAddresses;
    DWORD dwReqSize;
    DWORD retVal;
    DWORD count = 0;
    std::string tempForWstringConv;
    retVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, NULL, &dwReqSize);  // for knowing the required size

    if (retVal != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        return -1;
    }
    adapterAddresses = (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)malloc(dwReqSize);
    retVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, adapterAddresses, &dwReqSize);  // this time actually getting the desired content
    if (retVal != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES adapter = adapterAddresses; adapter != NULL; adapter = adapter->Next)
    {
        //outLog.push_back(Adapter());
        printf("\tFriendly name: %ls\n", adapter->FriendlyName);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you choose to down vote a post of mine I would like to know why in order to improve the way I ask question. should I show more research?

Comment: Wasn't me. In fact, I upvoted it. Because I think your question is legitimate and well formed.  I did slightly tweak your near MCVE to be complete. Also adjusted your printf statement, but that's not the root of your issue.

Comment: found a solution! posting now

Comment: do tell. because when I ran your code, I had no issues.

Comment: @sel: You *substantially* edited the question by changing the `printf` format string from one that was correct to one that isn't. It was using a Microsoft specific extension (`%S`) to the [format specification syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions).

Comment: %S and %ls are the same for printf.  Correct me if I am wrong.  But point taken.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found A solution!
meet *_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);*
the problem was that the output buffer wasn't allowing these characters because the mode was incorrect. Alas, our desired output:
[image]

inorder to use this you MUST A: switch all occurences of cout to wcou;  B: switch all occurences of printf to wprintf. C: include  and

Comment: Umm.. **no**.  Half of those print statement are showing garbage data.  You can't claim that's what it is.

Comment: that is hebrew. tested on a file aswell

Comment: good point, I should mention that, editing now (just making a presentable poc for a file, should take a few minutes)

Comment: Ah!  That must be it.  Yeah, the console is the one thing that doesn't automatically default to handling unicode.  Any other text control in Windows would do the right thing with widechar buffers.

Comment: If you examine the strings in the visual studio debugger, they will no doubt look correct.